# Err.clear in vbscript

Tags: optimization, vbscript, error-handling

in this vbscript the second Err.Clear is required or not as a part of optimization.

```
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   strSpoRootKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\"
   strKey = RootKey & "tcc\Operation\" & Version & "\Location"
   strPath = wshShell.RegRead(strKey)
   If Err Then
      Err.Clear  //first Err.clear
       RootKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node"
       strKey = RootKey & "tcc\Operation\" & Version & "\Location"
       strPath = wshShell.RegRead(strKey)
       If Err Then
           Err.Clear   // second Err.clear
           strErr = strErr & ": " & Version & ": " & strKey & ":error("  
       End If
   End If
```

Shall we remove the second Err.Clear from code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes second Err.Clear should be downside once error 
handled properly other wise it carry forward to next stage

so things will change to

```
If Err Then           
       strErr = strErr & ": " & Version & ": " & strKey & ":error("  
       Err.Clear   // second Err.clear
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of calling `Err.Clear` to explicitly clear the `Err` object after you have trapped and handled an error. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx9z5h4x%28VS.85%29.aspx) suggests that this is especially useful when you are using deferred error handling with [`On Error Resume Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h%28VS.85%29.aspx). This suggests that you really should be calling `Err.Clear` *after* you have handled the error that was detected, whatever that means for your particular application.

You didn't really provide enough of your code to suggest the kind of error handing routines that you're using. For example, if you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code above the block that you posted, and/or what you're doing with `strErr` to actually handle the error. Does your script end at the end of the posted section? If so, you're probably in the clear removing the second `Err.Clear`, since it'll be impossible for another error be raised anyway during the script's course of execution.

Regardless, I'm going to take the easy way out and suggest that you do the same: **there is absolutely no reason to "optimize" this code by removing any `Err.Clear` statements.** I promise that statement is not bottlenecking the execution speed of your script. Unless you are experiencing problems with your error handling routines (like trapping the same error twice or failing to trap an error because it has been cleared prematurely), there's little reason to worry about "extra" `Err.Clear` statements.